# block compete.com

Tags: alexa-internet

Is there a way to block compete.com or alexa from getting the traffic on my website? For competitive reasons, I don't want anyone knowing that info. I don't have advertising, just a paid-only site....would blocking compete.com or alexa in anyway affect my search engine rankings?

Comment: Apparently, we now know that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to block compete.com or alexa from getting the traffic on my website

As far as I know, Alexa and [Compete.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compete.com) both use user-installed toolbars that analyze what sites the user visits (similar to how TV Ratings are done; see e.g. the Wikipedia article on the [Alexa Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexa_Toolbar)). They do not fetch *your* traffic numbers as such; they estimate their own.

To mess with their counting process, you would have to block users with the Alexa Toolbar installed. While that *may* be possible, it's foolish in the extreme: You would be locking out innocent users, and decrease your Alexa ratings, which wouldn't affect them in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it easily and automatically without having to contact them.

For **Alexa**, you [can do it using robot.txt](http://www.alexa.com/help/webmasters)

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

The toolbar plugin is used to monitor traffic.

I don't have details for the others, but I've just found some information about robot.txt for **Compete**, **Quantcast** and **Alexa**: look a the end of [this article](http://blog.domaintools.com/2007/02/competecom-and-alexa-data-reviewed/) for practical details.

Please note that by adding that in your robot.txt it will also force them to remove all data they gathered retroactively.

This is useful for websites like [archive.org](http://www.archive.org) (linked to **Alexa**, in fact ia in ia_archiver stands for **Internet Archive**). They explain the process here: http://www.archive.org/about/exclude.php

Please note that in most countries, being able to remove your data from databases is a **legal right**.

Comment: Interesting. Will this block only their crawler, or the stats created through the toolbar as well?

Comment: This will remove everything. I'm going to edit the answer to talk about archive.org